# Vertical align DIVs within Parent DIV in IE7

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Wondering is it possible to vertical align X number of DIVs within a parent DIV.

All the DIVs do not have a fix height.

Working in all browsers but IE7.

[image: illustrated example]

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="left">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac faucibus nisi. Proin nec eros est, vitae rhoncus purus.
     </div>
     <div class="right">
         <img src="image.gif" width="50" height="50">
     </div>
</div>
.parent {
   display: table;
   vertical-align: middle;

}
.left, .right {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

IE7 does not support `display: table-cell;` property, it has support from IE8+

[**Check its Compatibility**](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell)

Edit:

As a workaround you can choose jQuery -

```
$(function() {
// vertical align function
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
        var ah = $(this).height();
        var ph = $(this).parent().height();       
        var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2); //var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;
        $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
    });
};

$('.greenBorder img').vAlign();
//
});
```

[**Refer this post**](http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2011/02/div-content-vertical-align-centermiddle.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, just like to know if there any work-around that. some clever css solution.